# w32 save as function for csv files in shopping list. | GO

Tags: csv, go, save-as

I am a GO beginner and need sone help.

I am trying to implement a save as w32 function in my shopping list project that i am doing in my school. Is this even possible?

When i choose the function in the console it just skips it and goes back to the console. Any tipps?

I have imported those in my model.go

```golang
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/gonutz/w32"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)
```

And this is the function:

```golang
func GenerateOutputFile() error {
    // Prompt the user to choose a file path using the "Save As" dialog
    var ofn w32.OPENFILENAME
    ofn.Flags = w32.OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | w32.OFN_NOCHANGEDIR | w32.OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | w32.OFN_LONGNAMES
    filter := "CSV files (*.csv)\x00*.csv\x00All files (*.*)\x00*.*\x00\x00"
    filterPtr, err := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(filter)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ofn.Filter = filterPtr
    title := "Save CSV file as"
    titlePtr, err := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(title)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ofn.Title = titlePtr
    buffer := make([]uint16, 512)
    ofn.File = &buffer[0]
    ofn.MaxFile = uint32(len(buffer))
    ok := w32.GetSaveFileName(&ofn)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("dialog cancelled")
    }
    filePath := w32.UTF16PtrToString(ofn.File)

    // Create the file
    file, err := os.Create(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating file: %v", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := file.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error closing file: %v\n", err)
        }
    }()

    // Write CSV data to the file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    if err := writer.Write([]string{"Name", "Count"}); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error writing CSV headers: %v", err)
    }
    for _, item := range Items {
        if err := writer.Write([]string{item.Name, strconv.Itoa(item.Count)}); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error writing CSV data: %v", err)
        }
    }
    writer.Flush()

    return nil
}
```

Appreciate the help.
Thanks !

I tried to ask Chat gpt about the issue, but none of the tipps are functioning. In the web i don't find too much about the w32 overlay in GO.